# Sync VSTS git in visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

Me and my team are facing a sync problem with visual Studio 2015.

We are using a Git repository with VSTS. Someone has worked in the master branch, and we need to merge dev and master, but anyone that try to merge dev into master, visual studio alerts that there are uncommited changes. looking into the changes tabs there are no uncommited changes. And the number of uncommited changes, change from user to user.

Very strange thing occurs here, can't find a way to merge the dev branch.

plz help!

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 has a few irritating bugs, this is possibly one of them. Try performing the merge from the commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with visual studio 2017 everything is ok. don't know if Edward suggestion is ok, but switching to visual studio 2017, the merge function works correctly.

many thx

Comment: If it is solved, you could mark it as an answer to close this thread to help more communities who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> visual studio alerts that there are uncommited changes

This almost certainly means that you have not configured your line endings correctly in your repository.

Likely, some users are using a mix of `core.autocrlf` settings.  If you have set `core.autocrlf=true`, but you have DOS-style line endings in the file in your repository, then any time a Git tool compares the file you have on-disk then it will do the CRLF conversion to produce a clean file.  It will then compare this to what's checked in, and the results will differ.  Thus, this tool will believe that you have uncommitted changes.

Set up a [`.gitattributes` file](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_1_gitattributes_for_text_files.html) that specifies the line ending conversion that you want to perform (I recommend setting `* text=auto`).  Then convert all your files to use the new line ending configuration (`git add --renormalize .`).

This will mitigate most of the problems with Git tools believing that you have changed files in your working directory when you have not actually done so.